# How to concatenate numpy arrays to create a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, organization

I'm working on using AI to give me better odds at winning Keno. (don't laugh lol)
My issue is that when I gather my data it comes in the form of 1d arrays of drawings at a time.  I have different files that have gathered the data and formatted it as well as performed simple maths on the data set.  Now I'm trying to get the data into a certain shape for my Neural Network layers and am having issues.

```
  formatted_list = file.readlines()     
  #remove newline chars     
  formatted_list = list(filter(("\n").__ne__, formatted_list))     
  #iterate through each drawing, format the ends and split into list of ints     
  for i in formatted_list:         
     i = i[1:]        
     i = i[:-2]         
     i = [int(j) for j in i.split(",")]         
     #convert to numpy array
     temp = np.array(i)
     #t1 = np.reshape(temp, (-1, len(temp))) 
     #print(np.shape(t1))
     #append to master list
     master_list.append(temp)
  print(np.shape(master_list))
```

This gives output of "(292,)" which is correct there are 292 rows of data however they contain 20 columns as well.  If I comment in the "#t1 = np.reshape(temp, (-1, len(temp))) #print(np.shape(t1))" it gives output of "(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)(1,20)", etc.  I want all of those rows to be added together and keep the columns the same (292,20).  How can this be accomplished?

I've tried reshaping the final list and many other things and had no luck.  It either populates each number in the row and adds it to the first dimension, IE (5840,) I was expecting to be able to append each new drawing to a master list, convert to numpy array and reshape it to the 292 rows of 20 columns. It just appears that it want's to keep the single dimension.  I've tried numpy.concat also and no luck.  Thank you.

Comment: For `x=np.array(mast_list)`, check both shape and dtype.  And pay attention to any `ragged array` warnings.  Sounds like your arrays are not all the same shape.

Comment: I have received the ragged array warnings.  I used a try / except to negate the random array sizes of 21.  My issue is with getting an array that is shaped (292,) to the proper (292,20)  With @Pantelis I have achieved that but can't get my data into the newly shaped array.                                                                                                            test_list = [np.random.rand(20)]*292
    master_array = np.zeros((len(test_list), len(test_list[0])))
    for i, array in enumerate(test_list):
        master_array[i, :] = array
    master_list = master_array

Comment: If the component arrays are all the same shape, e.g. (20,) then `np.array(alist)` will make a (292,20) with float or int dtype.  No further manipulation is needed.  `np.stack(alist)` will also work, giving an error if they don't match in shape.  Once you have a (292,) array, the only thing you can try is `np.stack` (or `vstack`).  Reshape CANNOT change the total number of elements.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think the random arrays of 21 elements are throwing me off, Will try these suggestions.  Appreciate it much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vstack` to concatenate your `master_list`.

```
master_list = []
for array in formatted_list:
    master_list.append(array)

master_array = np.vstack(master_list)
```

Alternatively, if you know the length of your `formatted_list` containing the arrays and array length you can just preallocate the `master_array`.

```
import numpy as np

formatted_list = [np.random.rand(20)]*292
master_array = np.zeros((len(formatted_list), len(formatted_list[0])))
for i, array in enumerate(formatted_list):
    master_array[i,:] = array
```

** Edit **

As mentioned by hpaulj in the comments, `np.array()`, `np.stack()` and `np.vstack()` worked with this input and produced a numpy array with shape (7,20).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried the np.vstack on my master_list of all the arrays in the file. now the shape returns as [0,] and the array itself returns [].  Not sure how to implement the other alternative.  I do know that rows have 20 elements, the odd ball has 21 which i did a try / except to bypass the few there are.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your formatted list?

Comment: Here is an example:1, 6, 9, 11, 12, 23, 25, 29, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 45, 51, 55, 59, 62, 70, 72]
[5, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 19, 28, 31, 32, 34, 40, 46, 48, 52, 59, 61, 69, 72, 74]
[1, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 23, 26, 31, 35, 44, 52, 53, 55, 58, 66, 70, 71, 75]
[3, 14, 17, 23, 26, 28, 34, 40, 42, 43, 47, 50, 53, 60, 63, 65, 66, 68, 69, 72]
[2, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 31, 34, 36, 43, 49, 50, 54, 57, 65, 76, 78]
[4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 19, 21, 30, 32, 35, 37, 42, 45, 46, 52, 54, 57, 60, 65, 75]
[1, 7, 21, 30, 38, 40, 42, 45, 46, 47, 50, 52, 57, 62, 64, 68, 71, 72, 74, 76]